# use a pointer to access an address specified numerically

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int * ptr = (int*)0x12345678;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I got a segmentation fault. But why? 
Because the virtual address 0x12345678 is not yet allocated? So why it is not allocated on the fly? But even if it is not allocated, there should be some bits at the address, and I can just print the 4 bytes beginning at the address 0x12345678 as an integer?

Comment: How do you know which type of data is stored at that specified address and whether the specified address is a valid address or not?

Comment: Please look at this page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: @haccks No matter what is stored there,  I interprete the four bytes it as an integer(using an int& pointer).

Comment: Arbitrary numbers don't all correspond to actual memory locations. Look up *MMU*.

Comment: You should specify the system which you are asking about, since the behaviour is implentation specific. On freestanding environment  the code could actually be valid, where as in typical hosted environments it's usually not.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to read memory outside your process' valid address range. The operating system (**not** the C runtime) prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

> I got a segmentation fault. But why?

Address `0x12345678` doesn't belong to current process which is accessing it.

I suggest to read [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Modern operating systems do not allow a program to access random memory wherever they want. That would be a major security hole. Any program attempting to dereference a pointer to memory unassociated with the process will exhibit implementation-defined behavior on modern operating systems, unless said program is a bootloader, kernel, etc. that can perform such operations.

You may *store* addresses to unassociated memory (i.e. not allocated, not memory-mapped) in pointers, but doing so is quite unsafe since dereferencing the pointer could fail.

Comment: That's not exactly true. Accessing memory through pointers is always defined. It might fail, however. A `mmap()` system call, for example, does not allocate any memory, nevertheless it's perfectly valid to access the returned address.

Comment: Nitpick: the behavior is implementation defined, not undefined.